# Assign hash value unless value is equal to something

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to update a key-value pair of a hash unless the value is equal to something. An example would be something like:

```
def sub(name)
  :name => name unless :name == "Matt"
end
```

Is there anything that can do something like that?

Comment: Your intention is not clear. is `"Matt"` a constant string? Where is the hash in your code?

Comment: Assuming the hash is in scope in your method, What you have is almost workable but needs to reference the hash: `hash[:name] = name unless hash[:name] == "Matt"`

Comment: So I'm trying to update a members information using the Gibbon API.

Something like 
    `gb.lists.update_member({
    :name => name unless :name == "Matt"
    })`

I tried your solution @MichaelBerkowski, but this is outside the scope.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand there are three things that you might want to accomplish, so I will tell you how to do all of them.

1) Assign `hash[:name]` to `name` if the current `hash[:name]` does not equal `'Matt'`.

To accomplish this:

```
hash[:name] = name unless hash[:name] == 'Matt'
```

2) Assign `hash[:name]` to `name` if `name` does not equal `'Matt'`.

To accomplish this:

```
hash[:name] = name unless name == 'Matt'
```

Edit:

3) As per your comment. I believe you need brackets around your conditional since it is inside a hash.

```
 gb.lists.update_member({ :name => (name unless name == "Matt") })
```

Comment: `{ :name => (name unless name == "Matt") }` produces `{ :name => nil }` when `name` is `"Matt"`; depending on `update_member`, it might change the value associated with `:name` to `nil`, not leave it unchanged.